# Converting an image into ASCII art in React Native

Tags: react-native, ascii-art

I am working on a React Native app that takes an image and converts it into ASCII art (in PNG/JPEG format so that I can add color). Which packages would I use and how would I do it? So far I haven't found a way to do it in React Native. I've found [a way](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-ascii-image) to do it in React but I don't know how I would translate it into React Native.

EDIT: I have tried to do it with Ionic React but the performance is much worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a module that doesn't rely on React at all to generate the ASCII, such as this one:
https://github.com/IonicaBizau/image-to-ascii

If that doesn't work, you could create a separate React Web app and use react-native-render-html to render the React Web app within the React Native app.

https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html

Comment: Thanks! How would I use that in React Native? When I tried the app crashed.

Comment: Please share your code. I've used "react-native-render-html" successfully in the past. I haven't used "image-to-ascii", but it looks like it would do the trick.

Comment: I meant the first one (Image to ASCII). Also, how would I use a React app with react-native-render-html? If I were to use it, wouldn't it affect the performance a lot since image to ASCII conversion is a demanding task?